# CollectionView pagination starting point for each item

Tags: ios, swift, pagination, uicollectionview

I would like each `UICollectionViewCell` to stop at 10 px from screen origin x. How can this be done?

[image]

Comment: https://medium.com/@shaibalassiano/tutorial-horizontal-uicollectionview-with-paging-9421b479ee94

Comment: Just add a leading constraint of 10 from the collectionview to the leading space of the superview

Comment: You may want to use custom layout to achieve it you may need to write your own collection view layout. You can see a sample one here https://github.com/maximbilan/UICollectionViewHorizontalPaging

Comment: **Same thing I have done with this** https://github.com/MillmanY/MMBannerLayout

Answer (score 0):

You can try any one of the options:

- Add leading constraint to the UICollectionView.
- Adding a leading constraint to UICollectionViewCell